# SQL - updating a field

Tags: sql

I have an sql table which has the following rows.

```
(4081, 3, '', 'contrapreneurship.jpg', 15.0000, '2007-07-09 05:16:35', '2007-07-15 12:41:03', NULL, 0.00, 1, 1, 0, 0),
(4082, 3, '', 'istandaccused.jpg', 12.9500, '2007-07-15 12:34:00', '2007-07-15 12:37:24', NULL, 0.00, 1, 1, 0, 0),
(4083, 3, '', 'excitingthesenses.jpg', 45.0000, '2007-07-22 14:00:47', '2007-07-22 14:01:24', NULL, 0.00, 1, 1, 0, 0),
(4232, 2, '', 'ambushindevilspass.jpg', 125.0000, '2008-07-11 11:00:19', '2008-07-11 11:50:36', NULL, 0.00, 0, 1, 0, 0),
```

Now the path of the images has changed. How do i update the field, that is update the filepath.
Should be something like this '/new/images/istandaccused.jpg'

I have several thousand rows like these. how do i procede on updating it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET ImagePath = '/new/images/' + ImagePath
```

This will do a bulk update on the table inserting `/new/images/` before the original `ImagePath` value.

I would strongly suggest that you encapsulate the whole statement within a `BEGIN TRAN`, so your statement becomes:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE myTable
   SET ImagePath = '/new/images/' + ImagePath
```

Then you can do a `SELECT` to make sure numbers are correct, and then either `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` the transaction if there are any problems.

Thinking about this a bit more, you should definitely add a `WHERE` clause so you only add the path to those records where an actual image exists.  There are 2 `WHERE` clauses that I can think of and they are:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE myTable
   SET ImagePath = '/new/images/' + ImagePath
 WHERE ImagePath IS NOT NULL
```

And

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE myTable
   SET ImagePath = '/new/images/' + ImagePath
 WHERE ImagePath <> ''
```

The first will *exclude* all records where there is no image and the image field is null.
The second is a combination of the first, but with the added check to see if an empty string has been added to a record.  There maybe a few more alternatives to this, but these two will get you started.

Comment: If `ImagePath <> ''` then its definitely not null so you only need `WHERE ImagePath <> ''`  in your fourth query

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty straight forward, since you're just pre-pending the path to the file name.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET field_name = '/new/images/' + field_name
```

You might want to consider adding a Where clause in case you don't want to end up with values that just contain the path

```
WHERE field_name <> ''
```